# Jakarta EE 10 - Eclipse - Dynamic Web Module (missing version 6.0)

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I created a project using Jakarta EE 10. Application works okey. I made a simple form and if I open html source code I can see strings like "`jakarta.faces.`" which I assume are result of Jakarta Faces 4.0.  I am using Wildfly 27 as a server.

Problem is that Eclipse (2022-12, v4.46) does not have support for Module version 6.0 and web.xml require version 6.0. for Jakarta EE 10 specification and it is showing me problems

`An internal error occurred during: "Loading descriptor for {project}"` org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xml.IllegalValueException Value '6.0' is not legal.

Same is for JavaServer Faces - in Eclipse my max version is 2.3 and for Jakarta Faces 4.0 needs to be 4, I assume.

I tried changing values in .setting/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml to

```
  <installed facet="jst.web" version="6.0"/>
  <installed facet="jst.jsf" version="4.0"/>
```

but then I get warnings about

```
Implementation of version 6.0 of project facet jst.web could not be found. Functionality will be limited.
```

Other thing is that I cannot use autocomplete on namespave elements xmlns:h="jakarta.faces.html"

Eclipse says "cant find facelet tag library for uri jakarta.faces.html".

When are we going to get Dynamic Web Module version 6.0?
Is there other way to setup Jakarta EE 10 in eclipse?

Comment: This is not a problem anymore. Dynamic Web Module 6.0 and 6.1 was added to latest Eclipse release.

Answer (score 2):

I confirm that Eclipse 2022-12 v4.26.0 does not contain Dynamic Web Module 6.0 yet; I guess it will arrive somewhere in a 2023 release.

Nevertheless, the Jakarte EE10 app that I am developing runs fine. I have set the version to 6.0 in the `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd"
    version="6.0">
  <display-name>AppName</display-name>
  ...
</web-app>
```

Maybe this helps for the time being?